# Too may redirects when i use the wp_redirect() function

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a plugin using the OOP approach but I'm running into a `many redirects` issue.

I want my plugin to redirect to a page when some conditions are not met after plugin activation. I keep getting `To many redirects...` error message.

My code is as shown below:

```
if (! defined('WPINC')) die;
if (! class_exists('AwesomePlugin')) {

    class AwesomePlugin {
        public function __construct(){
            //Register admin menus
            add_action('admin_menu', [$this, add_menu]);

            //Init plugin
            add_action('admin_init', [$this, 'init_plugin']);
        }

        /**
         *
         * Init plugin
         */
        public function init_plugin(){
            if(!isset(get_option("some_option"))){
                wp_redirect("admin.php?page=some-page"); exit; //This gives too many redirects
            }
            wp_redirect('admin.php?page=dashboard'); exit;
        }

        /**
         * Add menu and submenu items 
         */
        public function add_menu(){
            add_menu_page( 
                'Dashboard', 'Dashboard', 'manage_options', 'dashboard', 
                [__CLASS__, 'load_dashboard_view'], 
                plugins_url('logo.png', __FILE__)
            );

            add_submenu_page(
                '', 'Signup page', 'Signup page', 'manage_options', 
                'sign-up', [__CLASS__, 'load_signup_view']
            ); 
        }  

        /**
         * Dashboard page 
         */
        public function load_dashboard_view(){
            include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'dashboard.php');
        } 

        /**
         * Signup page
         */
        public function load_signup_view(){
            include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'signup.php');
        }           
    } 

    AwesomePlugin()   
}
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT:** I understand that no matter the page I'm loading, the init_plugin function keeps firing. As a result, it keeps redirecting the user to the sign-up, thus the many redirect error message. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue is caused when you initially call your file with the above code.

You should call the file that your code is in with the `include_once('path-to-your-file/your-php-file.php')`

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. You check happens every time admin is initiated, literally on every page of /wp-admin and (I think) every AJAX call. 
If you need to check this only on a certain page of your plugin management menu, you could use `$current_screen` global or `get_current_screen()` and use `ID` property of the object to check if the current page is where you want to do your checks. You can use [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) (under admin screen), to see what exactly ID you page gets as well as lots of other stuff you might find useful when debugging.